# Is there a canon map/layout for the House of Inspired Hands?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, battle-map, maps, waterdeep-dragon-heist

The Gondar temple The House of Inspired Hands is in Waterdeep and appears in Waterdeep: Dragon Heist.

This only contains a brief description of its exterior and interior, is there any more detailed canonical layout or map for the temple and its grounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No official map exists

There are a few brief mentions of the temple in various books in various editions, but I've never seen a map.